# AndroidTV TvInputService Implementation

Tags: android, android-tv

I am having problems with implementing TvInputService.

I have all information from the server concerning channels(end/start times, Uri addresses, id, name, etc..)

My objective is to create an app to setup streaming channels from this information gotten from the server.
I tried this http://developer.android.com/training/tv/tif/tvinput.html ... even thou I understand the theory (mostly), I am still new to this and because the website does not provide coding examples and thorough explanation of it, it is really frustrating.
I also tried the Sample provided by android, but that is too complex for what I am trying to do, and it just confuses me even more.

Can someone help me out by explaining(simple way, if possible) with some examples all about TvInputService implementation? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use my library, [ChannelSurfer](http://github.com/Fleker/ChannelSurfer), which greatly simplifies the development of TV input services.

There are a few main steps that you need to do to create an input service.

1. Declare what channels are accessible.
2. Declare what programs will be played on each channel
3. When a user tunes to your channel, how will the video be displayed

This is done normally through SyncAdapters and services, although this library boils everything down to a single class that you create based on your own specifications.

There's an example app as well if you need more help.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it out :)

Comment: I'm also having a bit of a problem understanding how, what and where, overal everything about the setup Activity... I've read your examples, but im still confused, cause both of them are very different, could you explain in layman terms on what there should be inside it, a small examples, as detailed as you possible can? That would help me out a ton :)

Comment: @Mokrab did you make sure you have the correct permissions and manifest details?

Let's start with a simple `InputProvider`:


    @Override
    public List<Channel> getAllChannels(Context mContext) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Get all channels");
        List<Channel> channels = new ArrayList<>();
        channels.add(new Channel()
            .setName("Time.Is")
            .setNumber("1"));
        return channels;
    }

This creates the channels for your service.

Comment: @Override
    public List<Program> getProgramsForChannel(Context ignored, Uri channelUri, Channel channelInfo, long startTimeMs, long endTimeMs) {
    p = new Program.Builder(getGenericProgram(channelInfo))
                        .setTitle("What Time is It?")
                        .setInternalProviderData("http://time.is")
                        .setDescription("A website that updates continually")
                        .build();
    }

This will add a new program to the channel and will appear in the guide.

Comment: @Override
    public boolean onTune(Channel channel) {
    play(getProgramRightNow(channel).getInternalProviderData());
}

When the user tunes to a particular channel, you will tell the system to start playing a video that corresponds to the current program in the guide.

Comment: I managed something, but what I am aiming for is to use the StreaminginputProvider,cause I have to use URLs that I retrieved from the server. After testing some, it doesn't throw an error, but is stuck at "applying batch update" and on the screen its stuck at "Setting up channels", I cant seem to get the channels and programs to show up on the screen by the hell of me, been at it for a long time. Mr.Nick Felker, is it possible to contact you directly somehow,  I am very frustrated on this and, not many people know how to do this. I would really appreciate your assistance.

Comment: I am able to get channel information from tvdb,but how to play the content is not defined in any documents.Do you have any idea about that @NickFelker

Answer (score 1):

Based from this [documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/media/tv/TvInputService.html), those implementing TV input services should normally do so by deriving from this class and providing their own session implementation based on [`TvInputService.Session`](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/media/tv/TvInputService.Session.html).

Your app manifest must declare your `TvInputService` then specify the `BIND_TV_INPUT` permission to allow the service to connect the TV input to the system.

```
<service android:name="com.example.sampletvinput.SampleTvInput"
    android:label="@string/sample_tv_input_label"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_TV_INPUT">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.media.tv.TvInputService" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.media.tv.input"
      android:resource="@xml/sample_tv_input" />
</service>
```

You can check this [example](https://github.com/jpxiong/platform_cts/blob/dd40d693dfc3030cf8e9b0bf9f450f2276feb9ca/tests/tests/tv/src/android/media/tv/cts/StubTvInputService.java) on GitHub.

Comment: Thank you, I added the code in the manifest in the beginning, but the part im stuck is the TvInputService class itself. I cannot seem to realize what needs to be done on the moethods of TvInputServicce.Session

Answer (score 0):

I am getting "Unable to start auto-scan for 'Authorization' " after I try to install the channels. I am using files from ChannelSurfer, managed to make the provider and HOPEFULY the setup(still confused about it), but I'm stuck on this part... The console does not throw a single error but the TV says the above statement. Why does this happen and what are the possible fixes?